# Removing duplicate value from excel file using vbs

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to remove duplicate value from column U in excel file, while all other columns are empty. Since i am using UsedRange function i am encountering a runtime error. I am using the following code:

```
 Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(basedir & ss)
 Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets("Report 2")
 objWB.Saved = True
 objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(20), 1
 objWS.Rows("1:2").Delete
 objWS.Columns("A:T").Delete

 call  objWB.SaveAs(temp_file_bu2,24)
 objWB.Saved=True
```

I tried using Range function also for choosing column and it is not working. If all column under range of UsedRange are filled with duplicate value only the function is working.

Comment: U column is the 21th column. But your code is about column 20. Why?

Comment: Ya that was very stupid mistake. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all other columns are empty replace this;

```
 objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(20), 1
```

with this

```
objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: you have given VBA code while objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(1), 1 worksfor VBS

Answer (score 0):

Replace this;

```
 objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(20), 1
```

with this

```
objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=21, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Since i am working on VBS columns cant be used. Anyway objWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Array(21), 1 worked Thanks for pointing out the column number error

Comment: By the way what is VBS?